# how to extract specific tag using calibre

Tags: calibre

I only want to use a specific "< d i v>" of the htmls to create epub, say, all the other part is useless.

Because each of the htmls is about 20k, and there are a lot of junk informations, scripts, ads, ...

All I need the "main-content" div:

```
<html>
....
<div id="main-content">
....
....
....
</div>
...

</html>
```

I know its xpath is :

```
//*[@id="main-content"]
```

How to use it in calibre or ebook-convert?

Comment: You need to show some understanding of html to understand what has to happen here. Try editing in calibre editor to see if their search is enough.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for looking into it. I update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this can't be done automatically with Calibre. However, if it's possible to download parts of a website with a custom [Recipe](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/news.html).

If you're familiar with Python, you could also use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to scrape websites.

For more information, see [How to scrape websites with Python and BeautifulSoup](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe).